# zend 2: edit data before validation

Tags: zend-framework2

I'm using zend framework 2 and I need to edit the data from the form before validation.

With this function I will take the data from the post method, but do not know how to edit it because the object is a protected type

```
$request = $this->getRequest();
```

Answer (score 1):

`$data = $request->getPost();`

and do what you want with it...

then you can do:

`$form->setData($data);`